# Submit Button giving trouble

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a page in which a user can type his/her message and can save it.
And at the same time the page will also show the Existing Messages in it.

I am not being able to save the messages.
The messages show here are already saved in the DB.

On Clicking the submit button a Fobidden page opens up saying CSRF Verification failed. Request Aborted.

Please guide me where am I doing a mistake.

THE VIEW PAGE CODING IS:

```
# # Create your views here.

from django.http import HttpResponse
from home.models import dbmassage
from django.template import Context, loader


def index(request):

    #shows messages from the database
    home_message = dbmassage.objects.all()
    t = loader.get_template('C:/Users/NILESH/Desktop/Django-1.5.1/templates/home/index.html')
    c = Context({'home_message': home_message,})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))






    # handle submit message
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['submit_action'] == 'Submit Message':
            # attempt to do submit
            b = home_message(request.POST)
        if b.is_valid():
            b.save()
            message = 'Message Submitted.'
        else:
            # validation failed: show submitted values in form
            f = submit_b
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))


And the INDEX page coding I did is :

    <h1>The Messages</h1>


<h3>Type Your Message:</h3>
<form action='{{ request.path }}' method='POST'>
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" maxlength=80 style="width:300px">
<table>
{{ form }}
<tr>
  <td colspan=2 align=right>
    <h5>Maximum Length = 80</h5><input name="submit_action" type="submit" value="Submit Message">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


<h3>The Existing Messages:</h3>
  {% if home_message %}
  <ul>
  {% for b in home_message %}
      <li>{{ b.massage }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul> 
  {% endif %}
```

AND the settings.py CODE IS only the MIDDLEWARE thing::

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
# Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
# 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

)

Comment: Please edit your question and add that there.

Comment: Can you post your template?

Comment: you'll never reach the `POST` related code, if that's really your code, you'll always return before checking the request... :/

Comment: really? all trying to figure out what's wrong and nobody is curious why anybody would expect something to work after a `return` statement? :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add this line `{% csrf_token %}` under `form` tag:

```
<form action='{{ request.path }}' method='POST'>
{% csrf_token %}
...
```

And as Samuele said, your code will never reach the code under `return HttpResponse(t.render(c))`

**Views can be reorganized to this:**

```
    #shows messages from the database
    home_message = dbmassage.objects.all()
    t = loader.get_template('C:/Users/NILESH/Desktop/Django-    1.5.1/templates/home/index.html')
    c = Context({'home_message': home_message,})

    # handle submit message
    if request.method == 'POST':
      if request.POST['submit_action'] == 'Submit Message':
        # attempt to do submit
        submit_b = home_message(request.POST)
        if submit_b.is_valid():
          submit_b.save()
          message = 'Message Submitted.'
        else:
          # validation failed: show submitted values in form
          f = submit_b
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Just pass the `return` statement to the end of the method. The `POST` logic will only execute after the form submit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But the return HttpResponse(t.render(c)) is to return the messages already in DB.

So How is it related to the SUBMIT MESSAGE option??

I am confused..

Comment: I did as You said.
BUT again I am getting the same message stating
" CSRF varification failed. Request aborted."

Comment: Can you update your  question with the template code updated?

Comment: @user2474208 also, can you post the settings.py? Specifically `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: please delete` 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',` in 
` MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`  from setting.py and say result

Comment: Sir I have updated my Question with the thngs u asked to show..

Now please guide me ..

Comment: @PauloBu , ok but i think it's a test programm

Comment: Ok, you're view method still wrong. Take a look at mine closely, you don't need that first `return` statement. On the other side, you didn't post the `template` code. I need to see it

Comment: @28 I did as u said .. that error was solved ..
BUT then the message typed in the text field is not being saved in the DB
And so I will say It did not worked..

Comment: @28 I know, it looks like it, but still, just adding `{% csrf_token %}` to the form should fix this. I don't know why is giving the OP such a hard time this simple fix.

Comment: I created the Templates through cmd
md templates
ten in that again 
templates>md home
and inside the home folder i created the index.html page
and the code of index I have posted

Answer (score 1):

I you call return your function finished. i hope this code help

```
in views.py
    def index(request):
        home_message = dbmassage.objects.all()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = YourForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data

            message = dbmassage(...call your dbmassage field like cd['message'] ...)
            message.save()


    else:
        form = Your Form()

    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'form': form, 'home_message': home_message})
```

in template

```
<h1>The Messages</h1>


<h3>Type Your Message:</h3>
<form action='{{ request.path }}' method='POST'>
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" maxlength=80 style="width:300px">
<table>
{{ form }}
<tr>
  <td colspan=2 align=right>
    <h5>Maximum Length = 80</h5><input name="submit_action" type="submit" value="Submit Message">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


<h3>The Existing Messages:</h3>
 {% if home_message %}
 <ul>
 {% for b in home_message %}
     <li>{{ b.massage }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
 </ul> 
 {% endif %}
```

in form.py

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField()
```